# Is it OK to use any kernel version with any version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I installed the latest Linux kernel 4.9 stable release on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and I was able to boot with it. I'd like to know if it is right to use any version of kernel with any version of Ubuntu or is there any restriction? Pardon me if I'm being so naive.

Comment: In general it depends on how you installed it; however if it works it works, your system is not going to unexpectedly break down due to the newer kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is OK to use newer kernels. They typically get more support than older ones. You sometimes can see it being recommended as potential fix for issues with wireless, touchpads, and other devices.

Older kernels might not be a good idea, since they may not be supported and have security vulnerabilities, and less support for hardware.  Keep in mind that when installing custom kernel, you might need to apply patches and fixes to it yourself. By contrast , what you get with Ubuntu updates, are kernels that Ubuntu's kernel teams and security teams have reviewed.

Comment: Thanks! Even for the stable releases do I have to apply patches? If so, what those patches could be related to?

Answer (score 0):

If you are with the most latest version 4.9 kernel then you already moved to  16.04 or 16.10 releases of Ubuntu which have and support kernels above version 4.4 and above.

You can check this page : [Ubuntu Kernel support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support)

- Also according to the mentioned page, 12.04 can have most recent kernel as 3.13(also known as 14.04 HWE kernel).
- But, since you have a 4.4+ kernel version, you must be running 16.04 or 16.10. You can check that by running the following line in the terminal ( terminal can be started by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T). Enter the following command and press enter.

  lsb_release -a

It should give the details.